# Display alternate UserForm dependent on variable

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to display a specific UserForm dependent on the UserName environment variable.  I update the userform in various places throughout the code so I thought it would be easiest (and trivial) to create two independent userforms (with wildly different designs) then use logic to "Set" a UserForm object variable at the beginning of the code.  I'm clearly misunderstanding something here, cause when it gets to the .Show command, VBA errors:

```
Dim usrForm As UserForm

If Environ("UserName") = "redacted" Then
    Set usrForm = LlamaForm 'for specific user, form styled differently including picture of Llama
Else
    Set usrForm = NormalForm 'for EVERYONE ELSE, normal professional looking form
End If

With usrForm 'initialize UserForm and display wait message
    .Cancelbutton.Visible = False
    .Proceedbutton.Visible = False
    .Exitbutton.Visible = False 
    .labmsg.Caption = Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Starting background processes, please wait..."
    .Show vbModeless
End With
```

Am I making this too complicated?  I was really hoping to just change the referenced form object at the beginning rather than introducing logic with redundant code each time I need to update the user.  Any ideas or improvement would be appreciated.  Caveat is, because they are wildly different layout/design, I would *really* like to keep two separate userforms rather than manipulating a single one (which I know can be done, but that is more work at this point compared to understanding why my method above isn't working.)

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: @BrianMStafford Runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Does the code work if you make it WET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generic object, but you lose the early binding features

**Try this code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowUserForm()

    ' You can use a generic object, but you lose the early binding features
    Dim myUserForm As Object

    If Environ("UserName") = "redacted" Then
        Set myUserForm = New LlamaForm 
    Else
        Set myUserForm = New NormalForm 
    End If

    myUserForm.Show

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: This works great!  After thinking about this more, I believe my initial method was actually creating a new UserForm object rather than referencing those already created.  I do still need to understand why the 'New' needs to be there in your Set statements, but I will go read now.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ionizing Great! remember to mark the answer for others to find it.

Comment: New keyword is required to create a new instance of the class and assign it to the variable. 

Do check [Mathieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885632/1521579) if you want to keep intellisense working

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the code that's responsible for showing the form, shouldn't have to care for any controls on either form.

Error 438 is being raised, because the `UserForm` class does not have  `CancelButton`, `ProceedButton`, `ExitButton`, or `labmsg` members.

The solution is to either [lose early binding and late-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885632/1188513) these member calls by making them all go against `Object` (or `Variant`, but `Object` is more appropriate here), ...or to re-assess who's responsible for what.

Looks like you're making some kind of [progress indicator](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/progress-indicator/); when you start needing swappable object components *and maintaining early-binding is a necessity*, the correct tool to use for that is *polymorphism*, i.e. interfaces.

The linked article describes how to make a *reusable* progress indicator whose worker code is fully decoupled from the indicator form. What you need is something like it, except as mentioned near the end of the article you'll want the `ProgressIndicatorForm` **and** the `LlamaIndicatorForm` to implement some `IProgressView` interface, and have this `IProgressView` taken in as a dependency of the `ProgressIndicator` class, rather than it being hard-wired into the initialization code.

The hard part will be managing to expose the progress indicator events on the interface - that'll require a formal `ProgressIndicatorEvents` class to forward the `Activated` and `Cancelled` events to the `ProgressIndicator` class, similar to how [this class](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Battleship/blob/master/src/GridViewAdapter.cls) forwards events from an abstract view to another component.

Done right, you end up with the calling code looking like this:

```
Dim progressForm As IProgressView
If Environ$("username") = "redacted" Then
    Set progressForm = New LlamaProgressForm
Else
    Set progressForm = New StandardProgressForm
End If
With ProgressIndicator.Create("DoWork", Form:=progressForm)
    .Execute
End With
```

Where `DoWork` is your "worker code" - can be any `Sub` procedure that takes a `ProgressIndicator` parameter.

Obviously this is a lot more work than just coding against `Object` and I wouldn't blame you for taking the simple route. But the principles at play here are well worth looking into, if learning new programming concepts is more important than just getting it to work.

Comment: To Mathieu's explanation, I'd add [his article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) for reference about coding against the default instance

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth information.  While I will indeed be taking the simpler route to move beyond this (so much left to do elsewhere,) I will also look into the information you provided and continue educating myself, so I appreciate that you took the time to answer!

Comment: Ricardo, thank you for the article link, I really needed to read that.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I will definitely read your blog.  I am still waiting for our system admin to approve the installation of Rubberduck, so this reminds me that I need to remind them to approve it!  Thanks again for taking the time to educate.